# How can I imitate this view controller modal transition

Tags: ios

So I'm trying to imitate [the transition found in the Pocketcasts app](http://www.gfycat.com/DrearyBountifulCrow). The idea is to have a view controller emerge from the bottom of the screen when an item is clicked on, and the view controller can either be swiped up to go full screen or swiped downwards to dismiss it. I honestly have no idea how I would achieve this, so I'm wondering if anyone has dealt with it before. Ideally this would be done in Swift, but Obj-C works. Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. share your code here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really great video from WWDC 2017 that builds a similar component using `UIViewPropertyAnimator`. This allows for interruptible animations as shown in your gif.

The presentation is extremely well done, and provides sample code.

[Advanced Animations with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/230/)

[UIViewPropertyAnimator Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator)